# How can we compile our project if "Node-Modules" are not there? What to do when Package.json is not there?

Tags: angular

I am new to angular. Recently i was asked 2 real-time questions.
Recently in one interview i was asked this questions.
How can we compile our project if "Node-Modules" are not there? What to do when Package.json is not there?

Answer (score 3):

`Package.json` contains all the dependencies + some other informations about your project.

`Package-lock.json` is needed to 'lock' the version. IE: in the package.json you have typescript version 1.0.0 but in the package-lock.json you have typescript version 2.0.0. If you delete the node_modules and install them again, typescript will be version 2.0.0.

`node_modules` here where the scripts of the single packages you have defined in the package.json is located. Is a folder that contains a lot of other folders + files + dist file.

**What do I do when there isn't the node_modules folder?**

Simply do an `npm install` and then you can serve your application. When you push your project over a repo, `node_modules` folder is not pushed. (you can understand that better googling `.gitignore`. Also would be useless to push such an heavy folder).

**What do I do when there is no package.json file?**

Your project is broken. You can't install any modules, or run any scripts. It contains the basic configuration of your data-work.

Comment: @ShripadAvhad Then consider accepting the answer at some point ;-)

Answer (score 0):

We cannot compile ts files without node modules because it contains everything which is required to run or serve our angular application